# How to properly count nodes in the stack?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, nodes

I created this loop to count elements in the stack that are within the interval [-10;10], but when I return the answer, I can see, that it doesn't count the last node, is there something wrong here?

```
    public int intervalNumbers() {

        int counter = 0;
        Node node;
        for (node = top;
             node.link != null;
             node = node.link) {
            if (node.data >= -10 && node.data <= 10) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sort of *off by one* case.

```
for (node = top;
         node.link != null;
         node = node.link)
```

Because of the condition `node.link != null`, the body of the loop is not executed for the last node (as the last node's link would be null)

Change it to `node != null`